# SQL subquery runs slower than either query by itself

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, subquery, average

I have two queries that run fairly quickly by themselves--within a few seconds--when executed from PHPMyAdmin.

```
SELECT * FROM `testresults` WHERE `SCH_NAME` <> ''

SELECT AVG(pass_rate) FROM `testresults` WHERE `SCH_NAME` <> ''
```

However, when I use the second query as a subquery, the query runs so slowly that I reach the maximum execution time and get nothing.

```
SELECT 
      * 
FROM `testresults` 
WHERE pass_rate > (SELECT 
                      AVG(pass_rate) 
                   FROM `testresults` 
                     WHERE `SCH_NAME` <> ''
                  ) 
 AND `SCH_NAME` <> ''
```

It seems that the subquery is being executed for every row, although that average will be constant. Is there something incorrect in my query that causes it to be interpreted as though the average changes on each line? How could it be rewritten?

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery. Untested but something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    `testresults` as tr , 
    (select avg(pass_rate) as passrate from testresults) as tr2
WHERE tr.`SCH_NAME` <> ''
and   tr.passrate > tr2.passrate
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work in Transact SQL:

```
   select
    testresults.*
   from
    testresults
       inner join 
         (
              select 
                  AVG(pass_rate) as calculated_avg 
              from testresults 
               where sch_name <> ''
         ) p 
           on (testresults.pass_rate > p.calculated_avg)
    where sch_name <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are lot of records in your table having sch_name blank ie `SCH_NAME=''`

Try changing condition position in your WHERE clause of outer select query.
Conditions are evaluated left to right.

```
SELECT 
      * 
FROM `testresults` 
WHERE `SCH_NAME` <> '' AND pass_rate > (SELECT 
                                         AVG(pass_rate) 
                                        FROM `testresults` 
                                        WHERE `SCH_NAME` <> ''
                                      )
```

If a record has `SCH_NAME=''` , the subquery won't be evaluted for it i.e. when using **AND** operator ,if first condition evaluates to false , second condition is not evaluated . This called sh[ort circuiting](http://www.gailer-net.de/tutorials/java/Notes/chap40/ch40_2.html).

A better way is to evaluate  AVG(pass_rate) once , store the result in a variable and use this variable in where condition instead of subquery.

```
 Declare @var int
    SET @var = (SELECT  AVG(pass_rate) 
               FROM `testresults` 
               WHERE `SCH_NAME` <> '')

     SELECT 
              * 
        FROM `testresults` 
        WHERE `SCH_NAME` <> '' AND pass_rate >@var
```